# Trouble with configuring users and connecting to Mongo with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, user-controls

I installed mongo 3.0.0 on my ubuntu server.
I tried to use PHP (with appropriate lib installed) to connect to mongo to learn sth new. Unfortunaltey I cannot go any further.
My user configuration looks like this:

```
> use testdb
switched to db testdb
> show users
{
    "_id" : "testdb.testdb",
    "user" : "testdb",
    "db" : "testdb",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "testdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I try to execute the following PHP code:

```
try{
    $uri = "mongodb://testdb:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/testdb";
    $options = array("connectTimeoutMS" => 30000);
    $client = new MongoClient($uri, $options );
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$db = $client->selectDB("testdb");
```

I get "Message: Failed to connect to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017: Authentication failed on database 'testdb' with username 'testdb': auth failed".

In /etc/mongod.conf I have "auth = true" uncommented

I also verified the conncetion with:

```
> nc -w 3 -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 27017 Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 27017
> port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

I dig through Internet, i spent few hours already on this, I even re-installed mongo and set everything up again without any success.
Could you point to where to look for solution?

Comment: Have you restarted `mongod` after activating auth? Also, you should add a user with the role `userAdminAnyDatabase` to the admin database before restarting mongod after enabling authentication. Be aware that this user can easily give away root rights, so choose your password wisely. ;)

Comment: @Markus: Thank you for quick response. Yes, I restarted mongod after uncommenting auth in conf file. Is order of creating users important here? I have just added userAdminAnyDatabase. Unfortunately the result for testdb user is still the same. I tried to connect with newly create user with role You mentioned but also unsuccessfuly

Comment: Try [Normunds Kalnberzins' solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29052015/1296707), please. He seems to have a point. Don't forget to upvote and accept, either. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication schema of 3.0 is not compatible with 2.x drivers. One way you should be able to make it work is by downgrading the authentication mechanism:

```
use "admin"
var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
schema.currentVersion = 3
db.system.version.save(schema)
```

Then create a user and you should be able to connect with it.