# Can't authenticate on mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, authentication, ubuntu-14.04

**What i've done:**

Enabled authentication in `/etc/mongod.conf` :

```
auth = true
```

Created the first user from the shell as stated in the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) :

```
db.createUser(
{
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "admin",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
})
```

Using the `admin` user, i've created a `root` user to access mongodb:

```
db.createUser(
{
    user: "root",
    pwd: "root",
    roles: [ "root" ]
})
```

Until this point all works fine, as i can authenticate from the mongo shell with:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u root -p root  admin
```

and it works perfectly, as i can make all operations in the db.

**The problem**:

when i try to authenticate from PHP using the same `root` user:

```
$client = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/admin");
```

It gives the error:

> Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'admin' with username 'root': auth failed

Why can't PHP authenticate on mongodb if authenticating with the same credentials works fine from the mongo shell?

**Other notes:**

- If I disable authentication PHP connects perfectly, and the mongo classes work fine
- I've tried to create different users, but the response is the same
- I am using Mongo 3.0.1, PHP 5.5.9 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64bit

Comment: provide port number with connection URL, may it connect.
For Example : 
`$client = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/admin");`

Comment: already tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried the other way: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.auth.php ? Can you connect without creds? Make sure the connection to the server is not reachable because of connection issues or something

Comment: I have also noticed that by default PHP will auth against the admin database, maybe adding the db name is causing some problems?

Comment: i've tried the "other way" but had no luck. I can connect without creds only if authentication is disabled on mongodb config file. Yes, it tries to auth to the admin database, but i have tried either to use another db and to not specify te db, but can't authenticate anyway

Comment: Resolved with this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050410/trouble-with-configuring-users-and-connecting-to-mongo-with-php/29052015#29052015

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Problem solved: apparenty it was caused by a problem/bug in the PHP mongo driver version `1.4`

I've upgraded the driver to version `1.6` with:

```
pecl upgrade mongo
```

and now the authentication works.

Comment: Thanks to you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, in my case I've installed mongo using apt-get

```
apt-get install php5-mongo
```

And seems that Ubuntu repositories has still the version 1.4 and hasn't updated the package yet.
If you want to install mongo on Ubuntu you should use the pecl option

```
pecl install mongo
```

Never use `apt-get` for installing mongo for php.