# PHP MongoDB Auth Fails

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using linux (Ubuntu 15.04) for a web project. Somehow I managed to install mongodb. I have created a user and I can connect to the database via terminal.

But when I try to connect to the DB via PHP script it gives this error:

```
Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: Authentication failed on database 'user1' with username 'user1': auth failed
```

Mongo Driver version is 1.5.7. MongoDb version is 3.0.4

Also when I connect to the database via terminal it gives me these warnings:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-06-19T18:08:20.354+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

But it accepts db.auth(username, password) and auths successfully. I can use the db. But PHP won't connect to the database.

Please help. I am trying to find the solution but everybody says something different and no solution works. I am spending hours to just to make it work under linux. I hate linux and I will go back to windows if can't find a solution.

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792674/cant-authenticate-on-mongodb-with-php)

Comment: Thanks @Moppo. I will cry from happiness. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moppo's answer solves the problem:

> Problem solved: apparenty it was caused by a problem/bug in the PHP mongo driver version 1.4.
>
> I've upgraded the driver to version 1.6 with:
>
> `pecl upgrade mongo`
>
> and now the authentication works.

Thanks