# Unable to authenticate mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

From the mongo client it looks like I can authenticate:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('admin','SECRETPASSWORD');
1
>
```

But when I am trying to connect in my config file in codeigniter with this code

```
$config['mongo_server'] = null;
$config['mongo_dbname'] = 'admin';
$config['mongo_db']['active'] = 'default';

$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['port'] = '27017';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['username'] = 'admin';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['password'] = 'SECRETPASSWORD';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['database'] = 'mydb';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['return_as'] = 'array';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['write_concerns'] = (int)1;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['journal'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference'] = NULL;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference_tags'] = NULL;

$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;
$config['mongo_db']['test']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_db']['test']['port'] = '27017';
$config['mongo_db']['test']['username'] = '';
$config['mongo_db']['test']['password'] = '';
$config['mongo_db']['test']['database'] = '';
$config['mongo_db']['test']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['test']['return_as'] = 'array';
$config['mongo_db']['test']['write_concerns'] = (int)1;
$config['mongo_db']['test']['journal'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['test']['read_preference'] = NULL;
$config['mongo_db']['test']['read_preference_tags'] = NULL;
```

I am getting this error

```
Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'mydb' with username 'admin': auth failed
```

Comment: NO its not working I have updated my question again

Comment: In MongoDB, users are attached to databases. Obviously, your admin user lives in the database called "admin". So you need top authenticate against that database using the appropriate config option equivalent to the [shell's --authenticationDatabase option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-shell-authentication-options).

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792674/cant-authenticate-on-mongodb-with-php/29825760#29825760). It could be the solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

i use a simple library

create mongo.php in config.php

```
$config['mongo_server'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_dbname'] = 'yourdbname';
```

and Mongo.php in libraries

```
<?php
class CI_Mongo extends Mongo
{
    var $db;

    function CI_Mongo()
    {   
        // Fetch CodeIgniter instance
        $ci = get_instance();
        // Load Mongo configuration file
        $ci->load->config('mongo');

        // Fetch Mongo server and database configuration
        $server = $ci->config->item('mongo_server');
        $dbname = $ci->config->item('mongo_dbname');

        // Initialise Mongo
        if ($server)
        {
            parent::__construct($server);
        }
        else
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        $this->db = $this->$dbname;
    }
}
```

now you can check, in your controller:

```
function index(){
 $posts = $this->mongo->yourdbname->yourcollection->find();
 foreach($posts as $id => $b){
echo $b['somefieldontable'];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This changing the value of this variable:

**$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;**

to:

**$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = TRUE;**