# Codeigniter not working MongoDB Connection

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, database

I'm using Codeigniter MVC.I installed MongoDB but it doesn't work.

**I'm getting this error;**

`Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: SASL Authentication failed on database 'teknikserviscim': Authentication failed.`

**The config file is like this;**

```
$config['mongo_db']['active'] = 'newdb';    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['hostname'] = 'localhost';    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['port']     = '27017';    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['username'] = 'superuser';    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['password'] = '12345678';    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['database'] = 'teknikserviscim';    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['write_concerns'] = (int)1;    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['journal'] = TRUE;    
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['read_preference'] = NULL;
$config['mongo_db']['newdb']['read_preference_tags'] = NULL;


class PanelHesap extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('mongo_db', array('activate'=>'newdb'),'mongo_db2');       
}
```

Well. What Is The Problem ?
Thanx.

Comment: Error you have got led to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792674/cant-authenticate-on-mongodb-with-php) solution. Try if helps.

Comment: I deleted I'm not using thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB connection should be

```
$config['mongo_db']['active'] = 'default';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['port'] = '27017';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['username'] = 'admin';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['password'] = '123456';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['database'] = 'mydatabase';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['return_as'] = 'array';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['write_concerns'] = (int)1;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['journal'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference'] = NULL;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference_tags'] = NULL;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = FALSE;
```

and in `application/libraries` add this library

[GIT Hub](https://github.com/Abdulla-nilam/MangoDB-Codeigniter-Lbrary/tree/master)

and in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('Mongo_db');
```

And insert, update, delete example

[Check this](http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-edit-update-and-delete-data-in-mongodb-with-codeigniter/)