# Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Authentication Exception

Tags: php, html, mongodb, forms

I was trying to create a login form for my project using PHP and MongoDB. I am using MongoDB atlas for retrieve the data. But I am getting this error when I run the login.php file

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException: Authentication failed. in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php:337 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php(337): MongoDB\Driver\Server- 
>executeQuery('project.login', Object(MongoDB\Driver\Query), Array) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Collection.php(663): MongoDB\Operation\Find- 
>execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\login.php(19): MongoDB\Collection- 
>find(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php 
on line 337
```

I don't know what this error mean.
This is my login.php code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$conn=new MongoDB\Client("");
$db=$conn->project;
$collection=$db->login;
?>

<div>
<form method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $data=$collection->find(array('user' => $_POST["user"]));
    if($data == " ")
    {
        alert("Incorrect username");
    }
    else
    {
        if($data["password"]== $_POST["password"])
        {
            alert("Welcome ",$_POST["user"]);
        }
        else{
            alert("Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help ? Thank you !!

Comment: Seems like you're passing an empty string as your MongoDB host: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBClient__construct/

Comment: No, I have linked it to mongodb atlas in my code... here I just removed it .

Comment: Well, it's an authentication error, so the issue must be the URI you pass. Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792674/cant-authenticate-on-mongodb-with-php) out in case it's a driver issue.

Comment: Yes, I checked and its working with other form. But giving error with this form.